# RVM Error when installing Ruby using WSL2 on Ubuntu: Error running '__rvm_make -j16'

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, development-environment

I am reinstalling my environment after reinstalling windows 10. I was given instructions for installing WSL2 and using the Ubuntu distro, nvm and then node.js, and then rvm and ruby. My organization wants us on ruby version 2.7.4 specifically. I am sure that if I posted the full instructions that wouldn't be allowed, but I am going to post the code they tell us to run to see if anyone knows why I get this error. I have gotten it to work on this machine before, and these steps are repeatable on other windows machines because I setup an environment on my laptop.

Here are the steps I was told to follow:

**1. Install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Ubuntu**
• Search for the "Command Prompt" application using the "Start" menu
• Select "Run as administrator" from the right side of the search window
• Allow the program to make changes to your device and wait for the "Command Prompt" application to open
• Type wsl --install -d Ubuntu and press 
• The terminal should output "The requested operation is successful."
• Restart your computer to complete the installation.
• Open the "Ubuntu" application
• When it says "Enter new UNIX username:" add a simple username and press  (Note: usernames may not start with a number, and may not include capital letters)
• Where it says "New password:" add a simple password and press  (Note: you will not see any text when you are typing your password.)
• Where it says "Retype new password:" retype the same password from before and press  (Note: store this password somewhere safe. You will need it to be able to run commands in the future)
• The terminal should output "Installation successful!" and then print about 50 lines that you can ignore
• Type wsl --set-default-version 2 into the terminal and press  (Note: you should see a message starting with "For information on key differences…")
• Type wsl --status into the terminal and press . You should see a message including "Default Version 2", which verifies that the default version has been set correctly.
• Type wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2 into the terminal and press 
Wait for the "Conversion complete" or "This distribution is already the requested version" message in the terminal
• Type wsl --list --verbose into the terminal and press . You should see a message including "NAME Ubuntu VERSION 2", which verifies that the default version has been set correctly.
**2. Install Node Version Manager (NVM) on Ubuntu**
• Open the "Ubuntu" application using the "Start" menu
• Type curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash and press 
• Close the "Ubuntu" application
• Reopen the "Ubuntu" application
• Type nvm and press 
• If you see a message ending with "Note: to remove, delete, or uninstall nvm", continue below.
**3. Install Node.js on Ubuntu**
• Open the "Ubuntu" application using the "Start" menu
• Type nvm install --lts and press 
• Type nvm list and press 
• If you see a message starting with "-> v16.0.0" (or any higher number, like "-> 16.11.1"), continue to the next lesson
**4. Install Ruby Environment Manager (RVM) on Ubuntu**
• Open the "Ubuntu" application using the "Start" menu
• Type sudo apt-get install software-properties-common and press 
You may be asked to enter your Ubuntu terminal password
• Type sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm and press 
• Type sudo apt-get update and press 
• Type sudo apt-get install rvm and press  (Note: if you are asked "Do you want to continue [Y/n]", type "Y" and press )
• Type sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER and press 
• Close the "Ubuntu" application
• Open the "Ubuntu" application using the "Start" menu
• Type rvm and press 
• If you see a long message ending in "For additional documentation, please visit https://rvm.io
This is an external link.", continue below
**5. Install Ruby Version 2.7.4 on Ubuntu (This is the part I can't get to work)**
• Open the "Ubuntu" application using the "Start" menu
• If the "Ubuntu" application is still open from the last step, close and re-open to prevent errors with running the next command.
• Type rvm install 2.7.4 --default and press 
• Enter your Ubuntu password if prompted
• Type rvm list and press 
• If you see a message starting with =* ruby-2.7.4, continue below
• **If you encounter issues installing a version of Ruby via RVM, try the following in Ubuntu:**
• Run rvm group add rvm $USER
• Close Ubuntu and reopen
• Run rvm fix-permissions
• After running the last command, try installing Ruby again with rvm install 2.7.4 --default
• If you are continuing to have issues installing RVM, try running the following:
$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER
• After running, try installing Ruby again.

The install seems to fail when compiling and I get this error message:

"Error running '__rvm_make -j16',
please read /home/dylan9706/.rvm/log/1671650995_ruby-2.7.4/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation."

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a friend and they had the same issue. They sent me some links and told me to try it. Follow these steps.

1. Remove WSL from windows and reinstall:
   Follow the steps in this link https://pureinfotech.com/uninstall-wsl2-windows-10/
   Once you do that, go back and re-tick those boxes under "Turn Windows features on or off" to reinstall everything and restart. Once restarted, run wsl --unregister Ubuntu in command prompt to make sure it is gone.
2. Install prerequisites for solution:
   The items you need installed are WSL with Ubuntu and Node.js.
   Follow steps 1-3 from the question above to get there.
3. Install Ruby on Rails:
   Follow the steps in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-20-04
   It should be pretty straight forward from there. You will be able to install the version of ruby you want and get the gems you need.

This is the solution that worked for me so I hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

I also ran into the exact same problem. After googling i found out that Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS uses a different version of openssl, i think its 3. You need version 1 of open ssl to install old ruby binaries. Here is what i did

1. $ sudo apt install build-essential
2. $ cd ~/Downloads
3. $ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
4. $ tar zxvf openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
5. $ cd openssl-1.1.1g $ ./config
   --prefix=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g --openssldir=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g
6. $ make
7. $ make test (you might get a few tests failing but just ignore)
8. $ make install
9. $ rm -rf ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
10. $ ln -s /etc/ssl/certs ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
11. $ cd ~
12. $ rvm install ruby-X.X.X --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g  (where ruby-X.X.X is the version you want to install

Comment: or you can downgrade to ubuntu v20